# Ubuntu 18.04 not prompting for password after upgrading from 17.10

Tags: password

I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 and after booting, it doesn't ask for a password and automatically login.

Comment: Do you have any conf files at /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf or /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf? If so can you post the contents. I'm looking for a conf entry called autologin-user=<val>

Comment: yes /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf  file exists but  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/ directory is empty

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf? Do you see an entry in the file named autologin-user?

Comment: it has autologin-user= equals to nothing

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't booting from the installation media?